# Is there a way to get all the changes in a pull request from command line?

Tags: git

I have to find a way to collect all the code diffs in a pull request from command line. From github UI I know I can easily view the diffs and the branch names, however, I have to automate some task from command line. I tried to use `git diff branch1..branch2` to get all the modified files and code changes in the PR. But how do I figure out branch1 and branch2 from command line?

Comment: Pull requests are not a *Git* feature. The mechanism for obtaining what you'd need is different between various hosting sites. GitHub have at least semi-official support now through the stuff in the `gh` scripts, though, if you're looking for a GitHub-specific method.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub expose some technical refs from the pull requests.

For an open PR (without conflict I think), you can fetch the `refs/pull/<id>/merge` ref to get the resulting merge, and then check the diff between it and it's first parent:

```sh
# Assuming the 'origin' remote is the one containing the PR
# (and not the fork of the PR source)
git fetch origin refs/pull/123/merge
git diff FETCH_HEAD^1..FETCH_HEAD
```

For a closed PR, this ref is no more available, but there is still the `refs/pull/<id>/head` ref. Then you have to look at the commit graph to find the merge commit (or use some magic to get the child commit):

```sh
git fetch origin refs/pull/123/head
MERGE_COMMIT=$(git log --format='%H %P' --all | grep "$(git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD)\$" | cut -f1 -d' ')
git diff FETCH_HEAD..${MERGE_COMMIT}
```

There is also another solution without using git: getting the diff from GitHub API (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#get-a-pull-request):

```sh
curl -L -u <username> -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff" https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/pulls/<id>
```